# redirect to previous action through remote in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building  application where most of all the request are ajax or remote form ( new,create,show,edit etc.). i am just updating a common div on each request.

now i need a back button, onclick the div must be updated with previous contents (somewhat similar to gmail's back link)

can anyone tell me how it can be achieved in rails 3.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to bookmark/historize the urls.

Let's say you have an ajax submit button form with the `submitButton` id :

```
$("#submitButton").bind("click",function(){

   // do you AJAX stuff here (form validation, form sending, etc.)
   $.getScript(this.href);
   history.pushState(null, "", this.href);
});

$(window).bind("popstate",function(){
   $.getScript(location.href);
});
```

With this code, you are enabling the back button history.

Please refer to [that SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106974/how-can-i-learn-about-enabling-the-back-button-in-a-jquery-ajax-application) for more information.